# RouterOS port forward

Tags: router, port-forwarding, mikrotik-routeros

I want to port-forward HTTP traffic from 1.1.66.166:80 to LAN-ip 10.13.37.10:80 on my router running `RouterOS 6.40`

Configuration:

```
/ip address print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 #   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 0   10.13.37.62/26     10.13.37.0      ether2                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 1   1.1.66.166/27      1.1.66.160      ether1 

/ip firewall nat print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 0    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=10.13.37.10 protocol=tcp dst-address=1.1.66.166 dst-port=80 log=yes log-prefix="" 

 1    chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=ether1 log=no
```

But no traffic is reaching the internal host. Am I missing something here?

I have verified that I can reach `10.13.37.10:80` from the router.

I dó get logging that the rule has been triggered:

```
firewall,info dstnat: in:ether1 out:(none), src-mac xx:xx:d0:xx:3c:00, proto TCP (SYN), xx.xx.174.107:22880->1.1.66.166:80, len 60
```

Comment: Since rule 0 has log=yes, are you seeing any log messages from it?

Comment: I do, but out: interface is (none).. can't set it to ether2 because I get an error

Comment: That makes sense since DNAT happens early, before routing (and before regular firewall filtering, too).

Comment: Add a filter rule to log any traffic going to the internal host: /ip firewall filter add dst-address=10.13.37.10 action=log chain=forward

Answer (score 0):

Hope, it is only part of your firewall rules :) You shoud filter all incoming exept established and related!

As port forwardig is FORWARD, may be I should allow forward incomming packets to 10.13.37.10 tcp port 80?

```
chain=forward action=accept protocol=tcp in-interface=ether1 dst-port=80 log=yes log-prefix="---FORWARD-TO-80--- "
```

It is no security risk, because you allow forward incomming connection for 80/tcp. The final destination you manage with dstnat rule.

Notice, you should have established and related eabled:

```
chain=forward action=accept connection-state=established
chain=forward action=accept connection-state=related
```

because your web server in LAN will answer and its answers chould be allowed to reach remote client.